# How to pass a value in a constructor from one class and set the value in its default constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have a situation where i have to pass a value to a constructor from a class and i also have to call the constructor from another class but while calling the constructor from the second class i can not pass the value to its constructor.How i can achieve this ? I am trying to define the value in its default constructor , but while i am calling the constructor i need to pass the value which i want to avoid. This is my current scenario

```
// I have to pass the value here 
DNQLtrDataAccessor data = new DNQLtrDataAccessor(aValue);
```

This is the corresponding class:

```
public class DNQLtrDataAccessor {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DNQLtrDataAccessor.class);
  String val;
  public DNQLtrDataAccessor(String val) {
    this.val = val;
  }
```

And here is the other class where I don't want to provide a value:

```
public class UWCompanyInfo {
  public void loadData(Document document, Connection connection) throws Exception {
 //Here i can not pass the value 
 DNQLtrDataAccessor dataAccessor = new DNQLtrDataAccessor();
```

Comment: I edited your question. If you disagree with my wording feel free to undo my changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you define an overloaded constructor, you need to define default constructor explicitly.